Solving $(x^2-1)^2-({x^*}^2-1)^2\geq{0}$

Find $x^*\in[-2,2]$ such that for all $x\in[-2,2],$ the inequality $$(x^2-1)^2-({x^*}^2-1)^2\geq{0}$$ holds.

The given solution is $-1$ and $+1.$ While solving I come across the inequality, $|{x}^2-1|\geq|{x^*}^2-1|,$ but how to proceed since the terms in modulus can both be positive and negative?

All you have to do is minimize $(x^{2}-1)^{2}$ over $[-2,2]$.

Thanks for the answer, Can you be a bit more specific for the reasoning behind this?

It has to be true for all $x$.  As for $x =1$ we have $(x^2-1)^2 = 0$ we must have $0-({x^}^2-1)^2 \ge 0$ or $({x^}^2 -1)^2\le 0$ but that con only occur if ${x^*}^2 -1=0$.

Geetha290krm's reasonind is that $({x^}^2 -1 )^2 \le (x^2-1)^2$ for ALL $x$ so $({x^}^2 -1)\le \min (x^2-1)^2$.

$$|x^2-1|\ge|{x^*}^2-1|$$ for all x
So what happens when $x=1$
$$
0\ge|{x^*}^2-1|
$$
This is only possible when ${x^*}^2=1$
The proper solution is to think of $|{x^*}^2-1|$ as separate constant say $y$
So your inequality can be written as $$|x^2-1|\ge y$$
Assume $y$ is greater than 0 which is the least possible value the modulus takes in $[-2,2]$
For explanation's sake take $y=1$ then for example $x=\frac12$ wont satisfy
This is valid for any non zero $y$ as you can check (it is also a crude definition of minimum) or formally any value greater than the minimum can not satisfy
So we get $$y\le0$$ and since we know $y\ge0$ as it is a modulus we get only $$y=0$$


Find $t\in[-2,2]$ such that for all $x\in[-2,2],$ the inequality $$(x^2-1)^2-(t^2-1)^2\geq{0}$$ holds.

Assume that $t\not\in\{-1,1\},\tag1$ and suppose that$\forall x{\in}[-2,2]\quad(x^2-1)^2-(t^2-1)^2\geq{0}\tag2.$
$(t^2-1)^2=0$ is equivalent to $t=\pm1,$ so, from $(1),$ $(t^2-1)^2>0,$ so, from $(2),$ $$\forall x{\in}[-2,2]\quad(x^2-1)^2>0,$$ and, in particular, $(1^2-1)^2>0,$ that is, $0>0.$ This is a contradiction, therefore, $$\Big(\forall x{\in}[-2,2]\quad(x^2-1)^2-(t^2-1)^2\geq{0}\Big)\implies t=\pm1.$$ The converse is clearly true, so, in fact, $$\Big(\forall x{\in}[-2,2]\quad(x^2-1)^2-(t^2-1)^2\geq{0}\Big)\iff t=\pm1,$$ as required.

Changing the question slightly:

Find $\mathbf{t\in[-2,0]}$ such that for all $x\in[-2,2],$ the inequality $$(x^2-1)^2-(t^2-1)^2\geq{0}$$ holds.

Assume that $t\not\in\{-1,1\},\tag1$ and suppose that $t\in[-2,0]$ and $\forall x{\in}[-2,2]\quad(x^2-1)^2-(t^2-1)^2\geq{0}\tag2.$
$(t^2-1)^2=0$ is equivalent to $t=\pm1,$ so, from $(1),$ $(t^2-1)^2>0,$ so, from $(2),$ $$\forall x{\in}[-2,2]\quad(x^2-1)^2>0,$$ and, in particular, $(1^2-1)^2>0,$ that is, $0>0.$ This is a contradiction, therefore, $$\Big(t\in[-2,0]\quad\text{and}\quad \forall x{\in}[-2,2]\;(x^2-1)^2-(t^2-1)^2\geq{0}\Big)\implies t=\pm1.$$ Thus, by elimination, $$\Big(t\in[-2,0]\quad\text{and}\quad \forall x{\in}[-2,2]\;(x^2-1)^2-(t^2-1)^2\geq{0}\Big)\iff t=-1,$$ as required.
